# Is templating Terraform files a good idea?

Tags: python, automation, terraform, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

tl;dr: If you manage hundreds of terraform files, is it worth writing a high level engine in a fully fledged programming language to manages those files ?

I spend a lot of time, editing, copying, and changing terraform files for infrastructure changes. Although the cicd used to make changes to the infrastructure, deploying a new release, uses cp, and seds to change terraform files and create new ones.

I find that a bit complicated to introduce changes to our cicd pipelines.

I thought of having a set of template that I could manage using a python engine, to create files, plan and apply, ...

Is it a good idea ? Do you have experience, or have you tried that too ?

Comment: If you have hundreds of Terraform config files, then it sounds like the architecture is very sub-optimal. You probably want to re-architect.

Comment: See if terragrunt may help with your use case.

Comment: @MattSchuchard there is one file per server (group) deployed, eached server is deployed with its dependencies, I don't know how we can do better.

Comment: @taleodor, I'll test it; with Kapitan as it seems equivalent to helm but works for terraform files too.

Answer (score 2):

Generic templating of Terraform HCL modules (.tf files) seems like an almost insurmountable goal and you would lose a lot of smart editor and IDE support in the process.

You would be better off moving the changing values into .tfvars or terragrunt.hcl files and sticking to you sed script or subscribing to Gruntwork and using their terraform-update-variable script which has a lot of testing and functionality that might prove useful.

Comment: Can you provide some links ? I could not find gruntwork terraform-update-variable script.
Also I came accross Kapitan https://github.com/deepmind/kapitan; I thought of using it as an equivalent of helm for terraform files.